# Improving SQL query

Tags: sql, database, select

I'm trying to improve my SQL knowledge, and making sql-ex.ru excecises.

And now I'm stuck with such problem.
I have such task:

*The database scheme consists of four tables:

```
Product(maker, model, type)
PC(code, model, speed, ram, hd, cd, price)
Laptop(code, model, speed, ram, hd, screen, price)
Printer(code, model, color, type, price)
```

The table **Product** includes information about the maker, model number, and type ('PC', 'Laptop', or 'Printer'). It is assumed that model numbers in the Product table are unique for all the makers and product types.

Each **PC** uniquely specifying by a code in the table "PC" is characterized by model (foreign key referencing to Product table), speed (of the processor in MHz), total amount of RAM - ram (in Mb), hard disk drive capacity - hd (in Gb), CD ROM speed - cd (for example, '4x'), and the price.

The table **Laptop** is similar to that one of PCs except for the CD ROM speed, which is replaced by the screen size - screen (in inches). For each printer in the table "Printer" it is told whether the printer is color or not (color attribute is 'y' for color printers; otherwise it is 'n'), printer type (laser, jet, or matrix), and the price.*

**Find the laptop models having speeds less than all PCs. 
Result set: type, model, speed.**

I'm typing such query:

```
SELECT 'Laptop', Laptop.model,
Laptop.speed FROM Laptop WHERE
Laptop.speed < All (SELECT speed FROM
PC)
```

It runs correctly, but the website tells that it's not totally correct for any database:

*Note that this decision will be valid only if the products with `laptop` type will be located in Laptop table. For our database this condition is satisfied, because there are only three types of products and, accordingly, three tables. Therefore, a violation of this condition may be associated only with the restructuring, which, however, should also be borne in mind when developing applications with built-in SQL queries.*

What does it mean? And how can I improve my query?
Please, explain me!

Comment: Have you also read [this part](http://www.sql-ex.ru/faq.php?Lang=1#f1) of their FAQ section?

Comment: Fixed the answer. I thought your starting query was functional but slow. Didn't know that is was non-functional.

Comment: Which DBMS are you using? Postgres? Oracle?

Answer (score 2):

The structure of this database is a little quirky in the way it handles model; model is the key of the PRODUCTS table.

See if this alternate syntax works on your database; it uses so-called "inline views" to break the problem into smaller steps that are more easily understood.

1. Find the speed of the slowest PC:

   ```
       select min(speed) as SlowestSpeed from PC
   ```
2. Find the laptops that are slower than that tortoise PC:

   ```
      select laptop.model, laptop.speed from laptop
      join
      ( 
       select min(speed) as SlowestSpeed from PC
      ) as MyTortoise
      where laptop.speed < MyTortoise.SlowestSpeed
   ```
3. Get the model info for those slow laptops:

   ```
     select PRODUCT.model, PRODUCT.type, SlowLaptops.speed
     from PRODUCT
     inner join
     (

      select laptop.model, laptop.speed from laptop
      join
      ( 
       select min(speed) as TheSlowest from PC
      ) as MyTortoise
      where laptop.speed < MyTortoise.SlowestSpeed

     ) as SlowLaptops

     on PRODUCT.model = SlowLaptops.model
   ```

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT 'laptop' as title, 
       laptop.model,
       laptop.speed
  FROM laptop
 WHERE laptop.speed < (SELECT MIN(speed) FROM PC)
 GROUP BY model, speed
```

Answer (score 1):

All the queries are correct. Just add `DISTINCT` keyword to your query.

```
SELECT DISTINCT type,l.model,l.speed
FROM product p,laptop l
WHERE p.model=l.model
AND l.speed < all (select speed from pc)
```

Answer (score 0):

Your query uses a subselect that tests all PC against all laptop, however it would be more efficiently expressed if you first select the lowest PC speed and compare that against all laptops:

Like so:

```
SELECT 
  'laptop' as title
  , laptop.model
  , laptop.speed
FROM laptop
WHERE laptop.speed < (SELECT MIN(speed) FROM PC)
```

This disclaimer says that this query works because `laptop`s are in the laptop table and `PC`'s are in the PC table.
If you merge your tables very little needs to be changed in the query:

```
Computer (type, code, model, speed, ram, hd, screen, price)
```

And then do a query like:

```
SELECT 'laptop' as title
  , computer.model
  , computer.speed
FROM computer 
WHERE type = 'laptop' 
  AND computer.speed < (SELECT MIN(speed) FROM computer WHERE type = 'PC')
```

Of course the disclaimer is true for any query; if you change the layout of your tables, you need to change the query as well.

**If you want to pass Q17, you'll have to do a join on table product**

> It is assumed that model numbers in the Product table are unique for all the makers and product types.

So there's your unique key to join on.

```
SELECT 
  product.type
  , laptop.model
  , laptop.speed
FROM laptop
INNER JOIN product ON (laptop.model = product.model)
WHERE laptop.speed < (SELECT MIN(speed) FROM PC)
```

Comment: Well, I understood you, but this task(17) at sql-ex.ru still doesn't aplly my answer. Anyway, thanks for response.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT DISTINCT Product.type, Laptop.model, Laptop.speed
  FROM Laptop, PC, Product
 WHERE Laptop.speed<(SELECT MIN(speed) FROM  PC) AND Product.type='Laptop'
```

Right.

The result of Your query:

```
type        model   speed

Laptop      1298    350
```

Comment: This will also produce the same result:


select distinct Product.type as Type, Laptop.model as Model, speed as Speed from Laptop join Product on Product.model=Laptop.model where speed<(select min(speed) from PC)

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT DISTINCT type='Laptop', Laptop.model, Laptop.speed
FROM Laptop, PC
WHERE Laptop.speed < ALL (SELECT speed FROM PC)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
     select Product.type, Laptop.model, Laptop.speed
     from Laptop join Product on (Product.model = Laptop.model)
     where Laptop.speed < ALL( select speed from PC)
     group by Laptop.model,Laptop.speed, Product.type
```

Comment: Please consider expanding this answer so it will be useful to future visitors.

Answer (score 0):

SELECT distinct type, Laptop.model, speed 
FROM Laptop, Product 
WHERE type='Laptop' AND speed<(SELECT min(speed) FROM PC)

Answer (score 0):

SELECT DISTINCT product.type, laptop.model, laptop.speed

FROM product, laptop

WHERE type='laptop' AND

laptop.speed < ALL (SELECT speed FROM PC)

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).